On iOS Safari, what's a more responsive way to get the keyboard size or an above keyboard float button?
I am using window.visualViewport.height(the view's visible height) to work out where the virtual keyboard starts in iOS Safari. And I have it working and responsive once I have the window.visualViewport.height value stored in a variable.
However, when I initially have to get this height value for the very first time, it takes a while. I use a focus event listener to eventually call a function that initiates the listening with window.visualViewport.addEventListener( 'resize', function func() {...window.visualViewport.height...} which outputs the "no-keyboard view" size when it first triggers, but then outputs the correct "keyboard view" size on its second time triggering.
I can think of 2 potential workarounds:

a janky-workaround of maybe having JS automatically open the keyboard (get height) and close it quickly on page load, but I doubt it can be done without showing the keyboard visibly to the user.
a crappy-workaround for the initial slow movement could be to have a list of all the height values for all the iOS devices that you want to cater for, and then no longer use the visual.Viewport.height nor resize event listener at all.

Is there a better way to code this for iOS Safari so that it doesn't take so long to get this value for the very first time?
Code: full sample code below, it's working as I described (i.e. with delay moving the button when the keyboard first opens, but very fast after that).
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>

<style>
#menuBtn {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>



<body>

<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>

<button id="menuBtn">Test</button>


<script>

/*
    Variable declarations
*/
let keyboardStartPos = 0;
let menuBtnElem = document.getElementById( 'menuBtn' );
let originalElemCss = menuBtnElem.style.cssText;
let visibleView = window.visualViewport;
let maxViewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
let textAreaElem = document.getElementById( 'textArea' );

/*
    Functions
*/
/*
    Function below calls "listenForViewReduction()" only once and ends. After
    that "listenForViewReduction()" calls this function back after the view's 
    height when the keyboard's open has been successfully saved to a variable.
*/
function moveElemAboveKeyboard(){

    if( keyboardStartPos == 0 ){
        listenForViewReduction();
        return;
    }

    menuBtnElem.style.bottom = 'auto';
    menuBtnElem.style.top = ( keyboardStartPos - menuBtnElem.offsetHeight ) + 'px';

}

/*
    Function below is used only once to get size of visible view when the 
    keyboard's open. When this is first called, the visible view will not 
    be correct (it will still be the full view), but straight after the 
    event listener triggers a second time and reads the correct view. After 
    which it saves the value, calls back "moveElemAboveKeyboard()" and 
    removes the event listener (itself).
*/
function listenForViewReduction(){

    visibleView.addEventListener( 'resize', function func() {

        let visibleViewHeight = visibleView.height;

        if ( visibleViewHeight != maxViewHeight ){

            keyboardStartPos = visibleViewHeight;

            moveElemAboveKeyboard();

            visibleView.removeEventListener('resize', func );
        }
    });
}

/*
    Rest of code
*/
textAreaElem.addEventListener('focus', moveElemAboveKeyboard );
textAreaElem.addEventListener('blur', function() { 
    menuBtnElem.style.cssText = originalElemCss;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>


I've now implemented the 2nd "crappy-workaround" that I mentioned, I'll post it here as an answer in case anyone wants it (I've also tried to document it as much as I could).
Performance-wise it's perfect, and works great as is. However, it has the drawbacks of having to add data for every iOS device manually (it will still calculate it automatically if a device's data is missing from the list), I explained this all in the code's documentation. Also, changing the <meta name="viewport"... tag option will likely cause things to break (also explained directly in the code's documentation) potentially causing a need to adjust for any changes to it.
Code here: in full and working. Oh also, the crappy looking transition of the button moving up is just that it has no animation and it's faster than the keyboard (so looks crap), but you can always add an animation/delay to the movement in order to make it look good.
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<!-- Caution above, this code is set up 
for the current '<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, 
user-scalable=no"/>' options. Changing 
these options are likely to change the 
value of "maxViewHeight"  as well as no 
longer match "deviceHeightDic" appropriately, 
causing the need to re-update the dictonary 
keys and values or even cause the data to 
be too inconsistent for the dictionary 
feature to be of use -->


<style>
#menuBtn {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>



<body>

<textarea id="textArea">sampleText</textarea>

<button id="menuBtn">Test</button>


<script>

/*
    Devices missing from the dictionary 
    below will be calculated automatically 
    but the initial keyboard pop-up will 
    be a slow element movement 
    unless the dictionary data is added. If 
    the dictionary 'key' ('key': value) is the 
    same as what your device gives, then 
    the dictionary value should be too, 
    (don't add duplicate data).

    Code used to get number data for the 
    key and value ('key': value):
    ----------------------------------
    'Key': document.documentElement
        .clientHeight;
    :
    Value: window.visualViewport;
*/
let deviceHeightDic = {
    '628': 359.65625, // iPhone 13 Mini
    '548': 320.5           // iPhone 7
};
let textAreaElem = document.getElementById( 'textArea' );
let menuBtnElem = document.getElementById( 'menuBtn' );

/* Saves the original CSS so that it can 
    revert the changes whenever the
    keyboard is hidden */
let originalElemCss = menuBtnElem.style.cssText;

// The part of the webpage that's currently visible to the user
let visibleView = window.visualViewport;

/* Max height of the web page 
   that could ever be visible to the user. 
   Used to identify the iOS device in 
   "deviceHeightDic" keys, as well as for 
   the automatic working out of where 
   the keyboard starts. */
let maxViewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

// Keyboard's start position used to work out where to place the elements
let keyboardStartPos = deviceHeightDic[ maxViewHeight ];

function moveElemAboveKeyboard(){
    
    if( keyboardStartPos == null ){
        // The function below will set keyboardStartPos and call this function
        listenForViewReduction();
        return;
    }

    // Needed to undo the CSS value
    menuBtnElem.style.bottom = 'auto';
    menuBtnElem.style.top = ( keyboardStartPos - menuBtnElem.offsetHeight ) + 'px';
}

function listenForViewReduction(){
    /* Listen to all resizing but only acts on 
       a view height of lesser amount than l
       the max. This function will only be 
       called once (if needed), but when 
       called the event listener below will 
       run twice...first returning the max 
       view height, and second will be the 
       active keyboard reduced view height */

    visibleView.addEventListener( 'resize', function func() {

        let visibleViewHeight = visibleView.height;

        if ( visibleViewHeight != maxViewHeight ){

            keyboardStartPos = visibleViewHeight;

            /* Calls the function back as the 
               original function call has ended 
               due to this event listener 
               needing to trigger twice before
               getting correct height value */
            moveElemAboveKeyboard();

            // After getting the correct height value, the listener is no longer needed, so it's removed
            visibleView.removeEventListener( 'resize', func );
        }
    });
}

textAreaElem.addEventListener( 'focus', moveElemAboveKeyboard );
textAreaElem.addEventListener( 'blur', function() { 
    menuBtnElem.style.cssText = originalElemCss;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>

